# SqlDataAdaptor update and close connection - how can I close connection via data Adaptor

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldataadapter

I have the following code:

```
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim rst As DataRow = MyrstEdit("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = 19",, da).Rows(0)

rst("HotelName") = "My Cool"
rst("FirstName") = "Albert"
rst("City") = "Edmonton"

da.Update(rst.Table)
```

So, the above is nice and short. And it works rather nice.

And of course this being asp.net, then centralizing things like connection code (that I don't have to create over and over) is a also rather nice. And why bother with a connection during coding, so above reduces coding workload.

How then can I ensure the connection object is disposed and closed correctly?

From reading, since I do not open the conneciton, then

The Fill() does open, then close.

And I have to assume that the da.Update() ALSO must then by logic open, then close the conneciton.

However, I still should clean up the connection object after above is done.

Question:
Is disposing of the sql data adaptor object sufficient here to also dispose the connection object that the data adaptor is using?

eg:

```
da.Dispose()
```

The MyRstEdit routine is this:

```
Public Function MyrstEdit(strSQL As String, 
                          Optional strCon As String = "", 
                          Optional ByRef oReader As SqlDataAdapter = Nothing) As DataTable

    ' can pass custom connection string - if not passed, then default
    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = GetConstr()   ' global func to get application con string
    End If

    Dim mycon As New SqlConnection(strCon)
    oReader = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, mycon)
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Dim cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(oReader)

    Try
        oReader.Fill(rstData)
        oReader.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = True
    Catch
    End Try
    Return rstData

End Function
```

So, the return sqlDataAdaptor object must be holding the connection, since the scope in above routine is limited.

So do I have to dispose the connection object?
Can I do this with the sqlAdaptor?

I can't dispose/close the connection object in above sub, since my da.Update() in the calling code still needs that connection until I do the update.

Comment: I think this one could fall into the realm of splitting up the function along the lines of one function to get the data, with `using` statements which auto-close connections, and another one to update it, so the data object can be passed around more easily. I ran into this and TBH can't remember if I ever solved it well.

Comment: Thanks. The da.update() is only one line of code. Say I move that out to a separate new routine? I still don't pass back the connection object, and I don't have it in context. And if I do have to grab/get/keep a copy of the conn object in code, then I now have a extra var in that code. So, much of the question was thus why/how I can (or should) dispose of the conn object. That first code snip to edit is not a partial bit of code but is 100% of the code required to update. (I can even add rows this way - despite a id=17 for update after that edit I can add one row before I do the update.

Answer (score 1):

> How then can I ensure the connection object is disposed and closed correctly?

Don't worry about it; it's not your job. DataAdapter makes it, DataAdapter will clean it up

> However, I still should clean up the connection object after above is done

No, for the aforementioned reason

> Is disposing of the sql data adaptor object sufficient here to also dispose the connection object that the data adaptor is using?

Yes, unless you have good reason to believe that Microsoft's code has a critical flaw and their classes will benefit from your code micromanaging the resources they create..

You can also read the reference source if you want to know what they do internally

> The MyRstEdit routine is this:

It's hard to understand why it exists in that form; you'd be better off just passing a datatable around and creating dataadapters as and when you need them. `MyRstEdit` isn't well named; it doesn't seem to edit anything, it always overwrites the passed in adapter with stuff that a any passed in adapter might already know (the connstr and sql) and then doesn't really do anything that couldn't just be put to

```
Using da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = 19", GetConStr())
  Dim dt as New DataTable
  da.Fill(dt)

  Dim rst = dt(0)
  rst("HotelName") = "My Cool"
  rst("FirstName") = "Albert"
  rst("City") = "Edmonton"

  New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
  da.Update(rst.Table)
End Using
```

About the most useful thing it does is apply a command builder, but that's only a single line and only needed for an update..

Perhaps you could create an extension method that applies to a DataAdapter, that gets the first row, so you could say:

```
Using da As SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = 19", GetConStr())

  Dim rst = da.FirstRow()
  rst("HotelName") = "My Cool"
  rst("FirstName") = "Albert"
  rst("City") = "Edmonton"

  New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
  da.Update(rst.Table)

End Using
```

But it isn't saving much over "just using it how MS intended", and there is still that block of "data columns accessed by string and hence intellisense can't help" in the middle.

If you're looking to find ways of making your SqlDataAdapter life easier it might be an opportunity to skip it and have a look at Dapper instead; a set of extension methods on a SqlConnection that map classes to and from:

```
Using c as New SqlConnection(GetConStr())

    Dim h = Await c.SingleAsync(Of Hotel)("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = @id", New With { .ID = 19 } )

    h.HotelName = "My Cool"
    h.FirstName = "Albert"
    h.City = "Edmonton"

    Await c.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE tblHotels SET HotelName = @HotelName, FirstName = @FirstName, City = @City WHERE ID = @ID", h)
End Using
```

You still have to write the queries, but it's a one time op, or you could look at something like Dapper Contrib.. The main use here is that instead of being some DataRow object you access by "string column names" you have a first class VB.NET object - Hotel, with named typed proeprties, and dapper can create them from SQL queries and put their values directly into SQL parameters (another thing that is absent from your existing code)

Comment: Thank you kindly. My example works on one datarow but i could use a datatable when needed. MyRstEdit = My RecordSet edit). Saves fingers. Best would put that all into a class and then conn etc. is in context. As above I don't write using block (not the end of the world - I not 100% being a baby here!!! - but close!!!). I don't code the fill nor code GetCon() for these updates. And right after that Edit I could do a row.Add(). (so the final da.update works nice).  Yes I am being "minimalist". Why code things over and over? EF is a option but quite heavy frame work for just small update code.

Comment: and the dapper idea? Not looked yet, but it looks to be a VERY interesting road. I had avoided the dataset designer (and now the newer EF framework - they are both quite heavy - but do give strong typed objects and intel-sense for columns. ) It just a question of how big (or small) of a framework I want to adopt  some simple update code. However, some great ideas in your code and some great example code - thank you.

Comment: The dataset designer isn't bad, probably less heavy than EF; EF's doing quite a lot of generation at runtime.. For dataset designer it's mostly done at design time and ultimately makes stuff that looks a lot like the code here - a tableadapter is one collection of SqlCommands/Parameters in an array, a DataAdapter, it swaps the command in and out depending on which operation is called, then changes the parameter values - the rest of it is dataadapter donkey work. I've used it for a long time and like it because it's a good mid ground between SQL and EF, but using Dapper more for small stuff

Comment: When you say that the DataAdapter "will clean it up" do you mean that a DataAdapter will call .Dispose on the associated connection?

Comment: It's a bit more involved than that, but the simple answer is "don't worry; data adapter acts properly with regards to connection management"